# Angular upgrade to 16 throws typescript compilation errors

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, angular-cli, angular-upgrade, angular16

Facing many Typescript compilation issues after Angular upgrade from 15 to 16

Upgraded my app to Angular 16 using below commands
updated my Typescript to 4.9.5

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli --force
ng update @angular/material
```

Then ran
npm install
ng serve

Got many typescript compilations errors

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "My-App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "CMD",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^9.0.0-beta.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.1",
    "@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^7.0.1",
    "ajv": "^6.12.4",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-resize-event": "^3.1.1",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^14.0.0",
    "angular2-draggable": "2.3.2",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^2.2.0",
    "angular2-virtual-scroll": "^0.4.16",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "buffer": "^5.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "esri-loader": "^2.15.0",
    "macaddress": "0.5.1",
    "math-random": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "mydatepicker": "^9.0.2",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-click-outside": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-right-click-menu": "0.0.16",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.1.1",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "original": "1.0.2",
    "panzoom": "^9.2.5",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.34.3",
    "sass.js": "^0.11.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.5.0",
    "sshpk": "1.16.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "1.10.0",
    "underscore": "^1.13.6",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.1.0",
    "web3": "^1.2.11",
    "worker-timers": "^7.0.38",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1602.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1001.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "schematics-scss-migrate": "^1.1.7",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "tslib": "1.10.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Errors like

1. error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'imgTranslate'.
2. error NG8002: Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of 'svg-icon'.

1. If 'svg-icon' is an Angular component and it has 'src' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'svg-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: Why are you using --f flag? First of all, you should check your peers dependencies and check if your dependencies ara compatible with the new ng version.